# Which jQuery UI modules are necessary for animate to work correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

At the moment I'm trying to run the example given here

```
http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/#demo
```

If I try to download just the core from here

```
http://jqueryui.com/download
```

It doesn't work.  However when I download the full version it does.  Exactly what modules are needed for animate to work?  I don't want to unnecessarily bloat my library with features that I will not use.

Comment: When using jquery-ui, you have to include jquery as well. Did you do that? And what do you mean by 'doesn't work'? Does it give you an error or something?

Comment: Depends on how you want to animate. Do you use effects? Show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I need the following plug in

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Answer (score 1):

Hiya see here **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/tm72d/1/

I reckon by modules you mean which libraries need to included to get animate get going. (I have mentioned the line) from -- query animate page.

Sorry if I understood your question wrong let me know I will remove my answer. have a nice one, cheers!

**Helpful link**

http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

http://jqueryui.com/docs/Effects/Methods

**Libraries**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```